# Structural Induction: Metalogic Proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

I need to show that by structural induction that the truth value $V$ of a WFF depends only on the truth values of its sentence letters. In other words, I need to show show that for any WFF $\theta$ and any PL-interpretations $I$ and $I'$, if $I(\alpha) = I'(\alpha)$ for every sentence letter $\alpha$ in $\theta$, then $V_I (\theta) = V_ I' (\theta).$

I'm not sure where to begin because I'm not sure how to translate the former assertion into English.
Does anyone have any tips about how to proceed with the structural inductive proof?

Comment: These are two different questions you're asking. Do you have trouble understanding the claim ("translating it into English"), or do you understand what you are supposed to proof but don't know how to do it?

Comment: I know how a structural induction works. But I don't know how to start the Base Step because I don't understand what property of a WFF I'm supposed to be showing holds for all WFFs.

Comment: The property you're supposed to be showing holds for all WFFs $\theta$ is: "For any PL-interpretations $I$ and $I'$, if $I(\alpha)=I'(\alpha)$ for every sentence letter $\alpha$ in $\theta$, then $V_I(\theta)=V_{I'}(\theta)$."  (This is almost copied from the question except for correcting a typo: $V_{I'}$, not $V_I'$.)

Comment: I'm aware of that; what I was asking for was help translating that into English. I'm not sure how to do the Base Clause because I'm not sure what the definition of the property means in English.

Comment: Is what I have to show that "if two different sentences letters in a WFF have the same interpretation then the sentence letters have the same valuation"? Or do I have to show that "every interpretation of sentence letter in a WFF has the same valuation as its interpretation?" I'm not sure how to translate the property into a conditional in English so that I start the Base Step.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

Induction on the *complexity* of the formula $\theta$, i.e. on the number of occurrences of connectives.

1) Base step: $0$ occurrence of connectives; thus $\theta$ is made of a single sentence letter $\alpha$. Obvious.

2) Induction step: consider two significant cases: $¬$ and $∨$ (others binary conncetives: $\land, \to$, are similar).

2a) $θ$ is $¬ψ$, where we assume that the induction hypotheses holds for $ψ$. Obvious.

2b) $θ$ is $ψ∨χ$, where we assume that the induction hypotheses holds for $ψ$ and $χ$.

By induction hypothesis, for any interpretations $I$ and $I'$, we have that if $I(α)=I′(α)$ for every sentence letter $α$ in $\psi$ and $\chi$, then $V_I(\psi)=V_{I'}(\psi)$, and the same for $\chi$.

We ahve several sub-cases; consider the case $V_I(\psi)=$ **t** and $V_I(\chi)=$ **f**. Then $V_I(\psi \lor \chi)=$ **t**. But $V_{I'}(\psi)=$ **t** and $V_{I'}(\chi)=$ **f** and thus also: $V_{I'}(\psi \lor \chi)=$ **t**.

Conclusion: $V_I(\theta)=V_I(\psi \lor \chi)=V_{I'}(\psi \lor \chi)=V_{I'}(\theta)$.

And so on...

Comment: Where do these subclasses come from? I understand that I need to show that if I assume $\theta$ has the property (for the IH) then I need to show that $\neg \theta$ has the property. And I need to show that if I assume that (for the IH) $\theta$ and $\psi$ have that property then so much $\theta \rightarrow \psi$ but I'm not sure how your sub-cases fall out of that.

Comment: @Rusty - they come from the truth-table for $\lor$ (and similar for the other conncetives).

Comment: I must not have phrased my question well; I'm aware of the values that go into truth-tables for compound sentences. I'm wondering how your cases are illustrative of the IH.

Can you translates that IH into a material conditional for English for me or help me do so?

Comment: OH! Is the question at hand this: consider any possible combination of values that the valuation function produces for the sentence letters of a compound sentence. Then consider the very same combinations of values that the valuation function produces for the sentence letters of a compound sentence. Does the value that the valuation function returns change at all?