# Structural Induction Proof of Compositional Semantics

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

I need to show by structural induction on WFFs that every WFF, $\theta$, has the following property: For any PL (Propositional Logic) interpretations $I$ and $I'$ if $I(\alpha) = I'(\alpha)$ for every sentence letter $\alpha$ in $\theta$ then $V_{I}(\theta) = V_{I'}(\theta).$

I know that I need to show that:

Base Step: Every wff $\theta$ is s.t. any PL (Propositional Logic) interpretations $I$ and $I'$ if $I(\alpha) = I'(\alpha)$ for every sentence letter $\alpha$ in $\theta$ then $V_{I}(\theta) = V_{I'}(\theta).$; and

Inductive Step: Modus Ponens preserves this property.

But I am unclear about how to show the Base Step. I am unclear about how to start the proof because I'm having a hard time translating the stipulated property of $\theta$ into a conditional in English to go about giving a conditional proof.

Can anyone help me translate the property $\theta$ above into an English conditional statement (or give me a hint as to how I should) so I can do a conditional proof for the Base Step?

Comment: Induction on the complexity of the formula $\theta$, i.e. on the number of occurrences of connectives. Base step: $0$ occurrences; thus $\theta$ is made of a single sentence letter $\alpha$.

Comment: Is there a reason you are asking the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462016/structural-induction-metalogic-proof) again? You can edit your original question if you want to add details.